# how do i fix flutter app crashing on android version 9 and below anytime app needs to open another app

Tags: android, flutter, plugins, filepicker, url-launcher

My flutter app crashes anytime I need to open other apps from my application like,

- whenever file_picker opens file manager to pick files
- whenever url_launcher opens the default browser to launch a site
- whenever open_file_plus opens a file like a pdf file with the device installed default app e.g To open a pdf file with WPS

Anytime I click on the button to perform each of the above actions it crashes the app
it works perfectly well from android version 10 upwards but crashes on Android version 9 and lower versions.
I'm on the latest flutter version and the plugins are the latest versions too
How do I solve this issue pls?

I've tried it on different devices but the problem still occurs

Comment: Please someone should help me on this issue.. i've been on it for over 6 months now and couldn't just find a solution